# Method inheritance issue when porting Python to C#

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I would like to port some Python code to C#.

I am currently unable to replicate the following Python snippet in C#.

```py
class X:
    a = 'foo'

    def x(self):
        return self.a;

class Y(X):
    a = 'bar'
```

And when I use my classes, I get the desired behavior:

```py
a = X()
b = Y()

a.x() // prints "foo"
b.x() // prints "bar"
```

But in C# I am getting different results.

```cs
public class X {
    public string a = "foo";
    public virtual string xe(){
        return this.a;
    }
}
public class Y: X{
    new public string a = "bar";
}
```

And when I use my classes I get the following results:

```cs
X a = new X();
Y b = new Y();
a.xe(); // "foo"
b.xe(); // "foo"
```

Maybe it is not possible to reuse a base class method with inherited class attributes?

Comment: I would recommend not using such techniques if you can avoid them.

Comment: The code does not even compile. `public virtual x()` should return a `string` in its signature.

Comment: My bad Mati, code is over simplified here

Comment: One note that relates to all answers: you cannot define a method with the same name as the type they're in. So `virtual string x()` will always fail inside `class X`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to redefine `a` in a child class

```
public class X {
    public string a = "foo";
    ...
}
public class Y: X{

     public Y()
     {
        a = "bar"; // USE THE BASE CLASS [a], AND ASSIGN TO IT DESIRED STRING
     }
     ......

}
```

And more. As @ChaosPandition pointed out: `C#` best practices suggests to not use public fields directly, but use properties. Not that your code will not work, but it's not a way any `C#` programmer will write it.

Comment: You could have a base constructor that initializes a readonly field. Personally, I don't like seeing public mutable fields.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: edited answer to stress that issue too. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Tigran and @ChaosPandion. That has answered my question.

Comment: Your base-class is quite strange, either X() is a constrcutor (than you may write it UpperCase also), or it´s a virtual method. However `public virtual x` makes no sense at all

Answer (score 3):

The `new` keyword in your class `Y` makes you override the variable in the scope of `Y` **only**!

When referencing `X.a` you can only reference `X.a`, not the `new Y.a`. You can't override a variable in a deriving class.

You can do that with properties though like in this sample.

```
public class X {
    public virtual string A { get { return "foo"; } }
    public virtual x(){
        return this.A;
    }
}

public class Y: X{
    public override string A { get { return "bar"; } }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't work because your `x` method is defined in your base type `X`, not `Y`, hence it only sees your `A` string field, and not your derived.

What you want is a `virtual` property:

```
public class X 
{
    public virtual string A
    {
        get { return "Foo"; }
    }

    public virtual string X()
    {
        return A;
    }
}

public class Y : X
{
    public override string A
    {
        get { return "Bar"; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your example, it's hard to determine the specific use-case, if `A` is constant, you could have an overridable read-only property.

```
class X
{
    public virtual string A { get { return "foo"; } }
}

class Y : X
{
    public override string A { get { return "bar"; } }
}
```

If it is not a constant, but is instead immutable after creation, you could have a constructor argument.  This example is a more wordy version of the above, so I would recommend that instead.

```
class X
{
    private readonly string _a;

    public X()
    {
         _a = "foo";
    }

    protected X(string a)
    {
        _a = a;
    }

    public string A { get { return _a; } }
}

class Y
{
    public Y() : base("bar")
    {
    }    
}
```

Both examples work the same, however.

```
var x = new X();
var y = new Y();

Console.WriteLine(x.A); // foo
Console.WriteLine(y.A); // bar
```

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish the same in C# you'd want something like this:

```
public class X {
    public string a = "foo";
    public virtual x(){
        return this.a
    }
}
public class Y: X{
  public Y()
  {
    a = "bar";
  }
}
```

However, this isn't really the C# way of doing things. A better way, but keeping with the spirit of your question, would be:

```
public class X
{
  public string a{get;protected set;}

  public X()
  {
    this.a = "foo";
  }

  public virtual x()
  {
    return this.a;
  }
}

public class Y : A
{
  public Y()
  {
    this.a = "bar";
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to redeclare a on your derived class. Just set it within the constructor to its new value. Also use properties instead of public fields.

```
public class X {
    public string {get; set;}

    public X() {this.a = "foo";}
    public X(string a) {this.a = a;}
}


public class Y: X{
    // default constrcutor
    public Y() : base() {this.a = "bar";}
    public Y(string a) : base(a) {}
}
```

Now you may do this:

```
X x = new Y("bar");// results in "bar"
X y = new Y(); // also results in "bar"

X y = new Y("test"); // results in "test"
Y y = new Y("test"); // also results in "test"
```